# If $A$ is normal and $A$ and $B$ almost commute, do $A^*$ and $B$ almost commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose, $A,B\in \mathbb{C}^{d\times d}$, $A$ is normal, and $\text{dim ker}(AB-BA)\ge (1-\delta)d$. Does then follow that $\text{dim ker}(A^*B-BA^*)\ge (1-\delta)d$, possibly for different $\delta$?

This is known to hold for $\delta=0$ because there is polynomial $P$ such that $A^*=P(A)$. But here, if $v\in \text{ker}(AB-BA)$, then $P(A)Bv=BP(A)v$ need not hold as $B$ might not commute with higher powers of $A$, so one could assume that $v\in \bigcap_{i=0}^{d-1}\text{ker}((AB-BA)A^i)$, which would certainly imply $P(A)Bv=BP(A)v$ but then the dimension of this intersection is perhaps too small.

I'm not sure if the statement is true.

Comment: What do you mean by “possibly for different $\delta$”? Are you asking whether $\dim\ker(AB-BA)=\dim\ker(A^\ast B-BA^\ast)$ or not?

Comment: @user1551 $\text{dim ker}(A^*B-BA^*)\ge \text{dim ker}(AB-BA)$ would suffice. I think equality might not even hold in the unitary case.

Comment: But one nullity must be greater than or equal to another. If $\dim\ker(A^\ast B-BA^\ast)<\dim\ker(AB-BA)$, then you get an example of $\dim\ker(A^\ast B-BA^\ast)\ge\dim\ker(AB-BA)$ if you replace $A$ by $A^\ast$. I don’t see the point of your question.

Comment: @user1551 But $A$ shall not be replaced. I have given the assumption on the kernel of $AB-BA$ for fixed $A$ and $B$ and want to know if the same holds true for the kernel of $A^*B-BA^*$. I should have left out the phrase "possibly for different $\delta$".